# Eliminate pairs of observations under the condition, that observations can have more than one possible partner observation

Tags: algorithm, sas, matching

In my current project we got several occasions where we had to implement a matching based on varying conditions. First a more detailed description of the Problem.

We got a table test:
key  Value
1    10
1    -10
1    10
1    20
1    -10
1    10
2    10
2    -10

Now we want to apply a rule, so that inside a group (defined by value of key) pairs with a sum of 0 should be eliminated.

The expected result would be:
key  value
1    10
1    20

Sort order is not relevant.

The following code is an example of our solution.
We want to eliminate observations with my_id 2 and 7 and additionaly 2 of the 3 Observations with amount 10.

```
data test;
input my_id alias $ amount;
datalines4;
1 aaa 10
2 aaa -10
3 aaa 8000
4 aaa -16000
5 aaa 700
6 aaa 10
7 aaa -10
8 aaa 10
;;;;
run;

/* get all possible matches represented by pairs of my_id */
proc sql noprint;
  create table zwischen_erg as
  select a.my_id as a_id,
         b.my_id as b_id
  from test as a inner join
       test as b on (a.alias=b.alias) 
  where a.amount=-b.amount;
quit;

/* select ids of matches to eliminate */
proc sort data=zwischen_erg ;
  by a_id b_id;
run;

data zwischen_erg1;
  set zwischen_erg;
  by a_id;

  if first.a_id then tmp_id1 = 0;
  tmp_id1 +1;
run;


proc sort data=zwischen_erg;
  by b_id a_id;
run;

data zwischen_erg2;
  set zwischen_erg;
  by b_id;

  if first.b_id then tmp_id2 = 0;
  tmp_id2 +1;
run;

proc sql;
  create table delete_ids as 
  select zwischen_erg1.a_id as my_id
  from zwischen_erg1 as erg1 left join 
       zwischen_erg2 as erg2 on 
                   (erg1.a_id = erg2.a_id and 
                    erg1.b_id = erg2.b_id)
  where tmp_id1 = tmp_id2
;
quit;

/* use delete_ids as filter */
proc sql noprint;
  create table erg as
  select a.*
  from test as a left join
       delete_ids as b on (a.my_id = b.my_id) 
  where b.my_id=.;
quit;
```

The algorithm seems to work, at least nobody found input data that caused a error.
But nobody could explain to me why it works and I dont understand in detail how it is working.

So i got a couple of questions.

1. Does this algorithm eliminate the pairs in a correct manner for all possible combinations of input data?
2. If it does work correct, how does the algorithm work in detail? Especially the part
   where tmp_id1 = tmp_id2.
3. Is there a better algorithm to eliminate corresponding pairs?

Thanks in advance and happy coding
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any bugs after a quick read.  But "zwischen_erg" could have a lot of unnecessary many-to-many matches which would be inefficient.

This seems to work (but not guaranteed), and might be more efficient.  Also shorter, so perhaps easier to see whats going on.

```
data test;
input my_id alias $ amount;
datalines4;
1 aaa 10
2 aaa -10
3 aaa 8000
4 aaa -16000
5 aaa 700
6 aaa 10
7 aaa -10
8 aaa 10
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=test;
    by alias amount;
run;

data zwischen_erg;
    set test;
    by alias amount;
    if first.amount then occurrence = 0;
    occurrence+1;
run;

proc sql;
    create table zwischen as
    select
        a.my_id,
        a.alias,
        a.amount
    from zwischen_erg as a
    left join zwischen_erg as b
    on a.amount = (-1)*b.amount and a.occurrence = b.occurrence
    where b.my_id is missing;
quit;
```

Comment: Wow ... beautifull code. And it does exactly what I want. And it has better performance. You answered Question 2 and 3 in a really nice way. Now I understand how the original Version works and got an even better solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your third question. The following approach seems simpler to me.
And probably more performant. (since i have no joins)

```
/*For every (absolute) value, find how many more positive/negative occurrences we have per key*/
proc sql;
    create view V_INTERMEDIATE_VIEW as
    select key, abs(Value) as Value_abs, sum(sign(value)) as balance
    from INPUT_DATA
    group by key, Value_abs
    ;
quit;

*The balance variable here means how many times more often did we see the positive than the negative of this value. I.e., how many of either the positive or the negative were we not able to eliminate;

/*Now output*/
data OUTPUT_DATA (keep=key Value);
    set V_INTERMEDIATE_VIEW;
    Value = sign(balance)*Value_abs; *Put the correct value back;

    do i=1 to abs(balance) by 1;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

If you only want pure SAS (so no proc sql), you could do it as below. Note that the idea behind it remains the same.

```
data V_INTERMEDIATE_VIEW /view=V_INTERMEDIATE_VIEW;
    set INPUT_DATA;
    value_abs = abs(value);
run;
proc sort data=V_INTERMEDIATE_VIEW out=INTERMEDIATE_DATA;
    by key value_abs; *we will encounter the negatives of each value and then the positives;
run;

data OUTPUT_DATA (keep=key value);
    set INTERMEDIATE_DATA;
    by key value_abs;

    retain balance 0;
    balance = sum(balance,sign(value));

    if last.value_abs then do;
        value = sign(balance)*value_abs; *set sign depending on what we have in excess;            
        do i=1 to abs(balance) by 1;
            output;
        end;

        balance=0; *reset balance for next value_abs;
    end;
run;
```

NOTE: thanks to Joe for some useful performance suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it eliminates the pairs. But in productiv environment we got more columns and need to select them too. Sorry for not defining my problem in more detail. But your approach is also nice.

Comment: Than you did something wrong. ;) I built a small test set to test most possible scenarios and it worked. I then took your code to create dataset test (replaced variable name alias with key and variable name amount with value) and tested that as well. For both solutions. And it works. :) After reading your comment, i just tested with your example at the top of your post (outside the code block) and that works too.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I used my_id as key, not alias. Shame on me xD
First think twice, then post. Lesson learned :)